# heroku "We're sorry, but something went wrong." in cedar stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Basically my app works properly in the localhost but the pages won't work on the heroku server. I've read up on similar problem on stackoverflow concerning this but most seemed to have a problem with not creating the repo in cedar stack.

This is a very basic app (from a tutorial).

EDIT: Here is the log

```
    2013-01-28T19:52:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-01-28T19:52:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-01-28T19:52:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2013-01-28T19:52:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-01-28T19:52:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-01-28T19:52:21+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-28T19:52:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2013-01-28T19:52:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2013-01-28T19:52:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-01-28T19:52:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-01-28T19:52:21+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/pages/home host=vast-wave-3795.herokuapp.com fwd=91.237.136.162 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=12ms connect=44ms service=34ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-01-28T19:52:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=vast-wave-3795.herokuapp.com fwd=91.237.136.162 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=425ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-01-28T19:52:51+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by arisnr1client@gmail.com
2013-01-28T19:52:55+00:00 heroku[run.9316]: Await
ing client
2013-01-28T19:52:55+00:00 heroku[run.9316]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-01-28T19:52:56+00:00 heroku[run.9316]: State changed from starting to up
2013-01-28T19:52:59+00:00 heroku[run.9316]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-01-28T19:53:00+00:00 heroku[run.9316]: Process exited with status 1
2013-01-28T19:53:00+00:00 heroku[run.9316]: State changed from up to complete
2013-01-28T19:53:23+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by arisnr1client@gmail.com
2013-01-28T19:53:28+00:00 heroku[run.9652]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-01-28T19:53:28+00:00 heroku[run.9652]: Awaiting client
2013-01-28T19:53:29+00:00 heroku[run.9652]: State changed from starting to up
2013-01-28T19:53:37+00:00 heroku[run.9652]: Process exited with status 1
2013-01-28T19:53:37+00:00 heroku[run.9652]: State changed from up to complete
2013-01-28T20:54:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2013-01-28T20:54:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-01-28T20:54:42+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-28 20:54:42] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-01-28T20:54:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-01-28T20:54:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-01-28T20:54:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-01-28T20:54:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-01-28T20:54:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2013-01-29T11:17:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2013-01-29T11:17:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2013-01-29T11:17:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 58836`
2013-01-29T11:17:18+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-01-29T11:17:18+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-01-29T11:17:21+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-29 11:17:21] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-01-29T11:17:21+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-29 11:17:21] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=58836
2013-01-29T11:17:21+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-29 11:17:21] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-01-29T11:17:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-01-29T11:17:23+00:
00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=vast-wave-3795.herokuapp.com fwd=83.6.123.123 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=348ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-01-29T11:17:24+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/rails.png host=vast-wave-3795.herokuapp.com fwd=83.6.123.123 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=329ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-01-29T11:17:24+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=vast-wave-3795.herokuapp.com fwd=83.6.123.123 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=64ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-01-29T11:19:47+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:schema:load` by arisnr1client@gmail.com
2013-01-29T11:19:51+00:00 heroku[run.2504]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:schema:load`
2013-01-29T11:19:51+00:00 heroku[run.2504]: Awaiting client
2013-01-29T11:19:52+00:00 heroku[run.2504]: State changed from starting to up
2013-01-29T11:19:57+00:00 heroku[run.2504]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-01-29T11:19:58+00:00 heroku[run.2504]: Process exited with status 1
2013-01-29T11:19:58+00:00 heroku[run.2504]: State changed from up to complete
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pages/home" for 83.6.123.123 at 2013-01-29 11:20:22 +0000
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.11 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:58836
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__891476158821333251__call__3890590830324905565__callbacks'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/pages/home host=vast-wave-3795.herokuapp.com fwd=83.6.123.123 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=528ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-01-29T11:20:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
```

Comment: whats in the logs? ```heroku logs -t```

Answer (score 1):

Run `heroku logs` from the command prompt from the same location where you deployed from to see what is going on.

Edit: As Joseph said, looks like a DB issue:

`Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL` failed.

Answer (score 0):

Am guessing your app uses a database either mysql, sqlite etc. I had such a problem sometime back. Try running `heroku run rake db:schema:load`. This should take your schema.rb file and load it up into the DB. This fixed my problem